# alternator output v rpm

Tags: low-power

I have a chinese made genset (1 ph 220vac 5kw).   The engine is broken but the alternator is sound.  I want to re-use this alternator on a waterwheel to produce 12vdc.  What sort of output can i expect if the waterwheel turns the alternator at about 100rpm.    Is there a graph of rpm v V, I? What sort of rectifier is required?  Will I need to energise the rotor at start up?  It has about 20 stator poles and 2 rotor poles with 2 carbon brushes.

Answer (score 1):

If your Alternator is 2 pole it is reasonable to say that the broken engine was running at 3000rpm  making 50Hz.This would be at a reasonably high value of rotor exitation . It is plausible that a micro hydro could run at maybe 170rpm.So yes you could on the face of it charge a 12V lead acid battery.Remember that the Alt was rated for 5KW so that means about 22 Amps RMS current in the copper wire.The rectifier could be some 30 Amp shottkey diodes which are cheap these days .Now you are not out of the woods yet .The DC    volts needed for exiting the rotor wont generally be 12 so count on needing some kind of DCDC convertor.The power needed for excitation is significant and must be checked to make sure that efficiency is still reasonable .Also check your armature wire DCR because copper losses will in percentage terms be much worse than when the machine was making 220VAC .Generally speaking people use permanent magnet type machines for such low volt DC .

Answer (score 1):

If the rotor has two poles, the stator will also have two poles. The stator has a larger number of coils, but they are really making up just two poles. The RPM is equal to 120 X frequency divided by the number of poles, so the alternator was probably operating at 3000 RPM and producing 50 Hz as stated in another answer.

The alternator could be operated at a lower speed, but the voltage will be proportional to speed. At 100 RPM , the voltage will be about 220 X 100/3000 = 7.3 volts, a little less because of losses. You will need to mechanically increase the speed or electrically increase the voltage to charge a 12 volt battery.

Power output will be another problem. At 100 RPM, the power output will be reduced proportionally because the current can not safely be any higher than it was for 220 volt operation. The generator will only produce 100/3000 = 3.3% of rated power minus losses including field excitation. Since the motor is unlikely to be 96.7% efficient, the losses will probably exceed the power produced. Some losses will be lower at a lower speed, but some will be the same as for full-speed operation

It would help to mechanically increase the operating speed.